# Buying a mac pro (2013) overseas

Tags: mac-pro

this is probably a very dumb question but I would just like to clarify...I live in New Zealand, and looking to buy a Trashcan/Mac pro from Ebay, as it is a lot cheaper (including duty/tax) than buying one here on a similar second hand website...

My only question is can I simply plug in the relevant power supply to the mac pro and use it here? I've tried to google it but I keep getting stuff about macbook pro adaptors, and not much about the mac pro cable. Although I did see some references to Apple having an international power supply or something.

Anyway, any clarification would be super helpful. Thanks..

Comment: Do checkout the Apple refurbished program - what is sold on the bay of fleas is not always what you expect...

Comment: Yeah, for sure - I've checked the refurbished program but they have nothing close to what I am looking for power wise...and the ones on our version of ebay are always about double or triple the price for the same if not less power. I've managed to find a couple of places on ebay that have sold hundreds if not thousands of these units and seem to have great feedback. Definitely considering it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, ***all*** Macs are multi-voltage...
All you'd need to change is the plug at the wall end [or swap for another IEC cable]

From [Apple - Mac Pro Specs](https://www.apple.com/uk/mac-pro/specs/)

- Line voltage: 100-240V AC
- Frequency: 50Hz to 60Hz, single phase

It takes a standard IEC to a local mains plug. ['kettle plug' they're sometimes called, though technically inaccurately as a kettle plug has a notch out of it]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, lines up with what I have found too. As far as I know I just need to get the power supply here, which can probably be purchased anywhere not just apple. 

Just wanted to double/triple check before I think about doing it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What 'power supply'? You just plug it in the wall. Standard IEC to a local mains plug. ['kettle plug' they're sometimes called, though technically inaccurately as a kettle plug has a notch out of it] Picture added.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin you're right I definitely worded my post a bit weirdly, looks like I'll be fine if I go ahead.